# Most and the least frequent numbers and Outliers - Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, exploratory

```
id |car_id
0  |  32
.  |   2
.  |   3
.  |   7
.  |   3
.  |   4
.  |  32
N  |   1
```

How do you choose the most and the least frequent numbers from the id_car column and present them in a new table with as it often appears?'car_id' and 'quantity'

`mdata['car_id'].value_counts().idxmax()`

Comment: Using a Counter class will help you with the question of "how many of each".  You can read about it at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter . You can answer the second part of the first question, namely "which id happens most often" if you use most_common(1) (same documentation page)

Comment: @rajah9 Ok, I'm edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will provide the most frequent ID and the three least-frequent IDs.

```
from collections import Counter
car_ids = [32, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 32, 1]
c = Counter(car_ids)
count_pairs = c.most_common() # Gets all counts, from highest to lowest.
print (f'Most frequent: {count_pairs[0]}') # Most frequent: (32, 2)
n = 3
print (f'Least frequent {n}: {count_pairs[:-n-1:-1]}') # Least frequent 3: [(1, 1), (4, 1), (7, 1)]
```

`count_pairs` has a list of pairs of (ID, *count for that ID*). It is sorted from most frequent to least frequent. `most_common` doesn't tell us the order of ties.

You may change the n to 1 if you only want any of the least-frequent IDs. I made it 3 so that you could see that three tied for least-frequent.

Comment: Code in Python to Jupyter

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Can you copy the above code and paste it into a new cell in your Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Thank You! @rajah9 What if I have a lot of data? how to do it without entering them again from the data to cell in Jupyter?

Comment: After your cell executes, you should be able to replace the car_ids = [32, 2, .. 1] in the answer code with car_ids = mdata['car_id]. If you have a different question about Jupyter, you should ask it separately. We shouldn't have an extended discussion in these comments.